# My $? command succeeded code fails, why?

Tags: bash

In my bash script, I am trying to have `rsync` retry 10 times if it looses connection to its destination before giving up.

I know this code traps all errors but I can live with that for now.

My code is:

```
lops="0"
while true; do
    let "lops++"
    rsync $OPT $SRCLINUX $TRG 2>&1 | tee --append ${LOGFILE}
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        echolog "rsync finished WITHOUT error after $lops times"
        break 
    else
        echolog "Re-starting rsync for the ${lops}th time due to ERRORS"
    fi
    if [[ "$lops" == "10" ]]; then
        echolog "GAVE UP DUE TO TOO MANY rsync ERRORS - BACKUP NOT FINISHED"
        break 
    fi
done
```

It does not work as expected, here is a what happens on the first error:

```
TDBG6/
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (131505 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync finished WITHOUT error after 1 times
```

Is this because the $? contains the return value of `tee`, NOT `rsync`?

How can I fix this? (I am personally Linux syntax limited :)

Comment: `$?` has the return code of the last command in a pipeline (which is `tee` here). There is no clean way to get the return code from rsync except avoiding the pipeline. But you can try `set -o pipefail` (read up on pipefail in the bash manpage)

Comment: why not use --log-file option for rsync?

Comment: @Nuetrino My log files gets appended many times during a day and each day gets a new log file.  I don't see an easy way to have rsync mesh with my log file, perhaps there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least 2 possibilities to fix your problem:

1. use `PIPESTATUS`:

   > An array variable containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

   Use it as:

   ```
   rsync $OPT $SRCLINUX $TRG 2>&1 | tee --append ${LOGFILE}
   if (( PIPESTATUS[0] == 0 )); then
   ```
2. use `rsync`'s `--log-file` option.

Notes:

- you have lots of quotes missing in your code!
- don't use uppercase variable names.
- Don't use `let` and use `((...))` for arithmetic.

Comment: Your #1 works for me, least mods to my nasty code and I understand it.  Thanks for Notes and will do.  Am I just missing quotes around my variable insertions? :)

Comment: @KiloOne every expansion should be quoted: `"$opt" "$srclinux" "$trg"` and `"logfile"`. Now, if you happen to put several options in `$opt`, then you're doing it wrong: use an array instead. E.g., `opt=( 'option1' 'option2' )` and use as `"${opt[@]}"`.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are great!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other suggestions for working around the pipe confounding your exit code, you can avoid the pipe by using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) like so:

```
rsync "$OPT" "$SRCLINUX" "$TRG" &> >( tee --append "${LOGFILE}" )
```

which will redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` (that's the `&>` part) into a "file" that is connected to `stdin` of the process within the `>(...)`, in this case the `tee` command you want.  So it's very much like the pipe, but without the pipe (the pipe connects `stdout` of the left to `stdin` of the right behind the scenes, we've just pushed it out in the open here).

Comment: Wish I could select more than 1 answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the status is the status of the last command in the pipeline.

I don't know how to deal with this in general, but for this specific case you can just redirect the output of the whole loop:

```
while true; do
    ...
done | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
```

Depending on what it's for, this may also mean you don't need the "echolog" function.

Comment: Again, wish I could select more than one answer :)